# In boundary-value analysis, why test min+1 along with min?

Tags: testing, quality

In boundary analysis testing, some authors suggest testing MIN-1, MIN, MIN+1 (and the same for MAX).

Also for 1-100 range (if A>=1 && A<=100), test cases would be: 0,1,2 and 99,100,101.

I do not see the point - if 100 works, then 99 must work too (in my opinion but this is why I ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are off by one errors so common and what can we do to prevent them?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42895/why-are-off-by-one-errors-so-common-and-what-can-we-do-to-prevent-them)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets assume you are testing a class "interval", representing intervals of natural numbers:

```
 var interval= new Interval(1,100);
```

Now your first two tests are "green":

```
AssertIsTrue(interval.Contains(100))
AssertIsFalse(interval.Contains(101))
```

and you are confident the author made no "off-by-one-error".

Unfortunately, the implementation looks like this

```
Contains(x)
{
    return (x>= beginRange && x == endRange);
   // above line has a typo, "==" should have been be "<="
}
```

So you were better off to add another test at first hand,

```
 AssertIsTrue(interval.Contains(99));
```

which fails, revealing the bug missed by the first two tests.

Or to be more general: off-by-one errors do not always manifest themselves by mixing up "<" and "<=", there are lots of other possibilities to get such things wrong, and as a tester, you are better off not to make any assumptions about how the internal implementation of a function looks like.

Comment: Hmm, how could 101 pass if X==end range and the range is 1-100?

Comment: @user144171: read the code carefully twice, then you will probably understand.

Comment: @user144171 That's exactly the reason to test it :-)

Answer (score 0):

> In boundary analysis testing, some authors suggest testing MIN-1, MIN, MIN+1 (and the same for MAX) ... I do not see the point

The point is that your code is *expected* to fail for values outside the permitted range and that's what you're testing with these "extra" cases.
Not every test *should* pass; you need to test for [some] things that you would expect to fail - and correct the problem if/when they *don't*.

Comment: I don't think he meant why test min-1, he meant why test min+1, a value inside the permitted range.